# Can I use the OpenFileDialog in a WinForms pane?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

Is there a way I can get the OpenFileDialog in a pane of my WinForms Form?

I want to make a 2-pane "Open Files Dialog" where in one pane I collect the files that are selected in the other pane, which can browse between folders. I know, I could roll it myself, but it would be easier if I could use the OpenFileDialog as a component to drop in...

Comment: Don't know how to do it in C#, but you should create two UI thread, and than you have to do some hack to make them appear sticked to the pane... I'm quite dubious it is a way to go.

Comment: Fortunately, I don't have to do it like that in C# :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With enough effort, you can do practically anything, but I'm going to go with "no" on this one. It was never meant to do what you're thinking of making it do, and isn't well suited to your paradigm anyway. Roll your own or look for something someone already created, I'd say...

Comment: I'm certainly open to finding something someone has already created. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've never used anything myself. A little searching brings up some options, though. You might take a look at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15059/C-File-Browser)-- it seems like it might prove to be at least a good foundation to build on. (Note this is more about an Explorer-type interface, not OFD, but the concepts should all be there, at least.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to **drop in** the OpenFile Dialogue control to Winforms.The only option will be to use a custom control or Design one for yourself.Its quite simple,Create a Tree View for Folders on the Left pane and a ListBox for Files on the Right pane.

Comment: No; it's actually enormously complicated.  You need to interact with the shell to get namespaces, display names, icons, and context menus.  You also need good async loading.

Comment: Why do you need to Communicate with the shell there are inbuilt classes to do it.You can easily assign your own icons.I don't think there is a requirement for the context menu.

Comment: @SLaks I know it can be done.But what the user want is to DROP IN the control.

Comment: I'm disagreeing with your statement about being quite simple.  Even without context menus (and end-users will want context menus), it's still enormously complicated.

Comment: How complicated this is becomes entirely dependant on how complicated you want to make it.  Simple tree, default icons, simple list.  No context menus, no drag and drop, and minimal support for folder navigation via double-click.  Pretty simple.  The more feature you add in, the more complex this gets, exponentially so in most cases.